# Comparing strings in C# with OR in an if statement

Tags: c#, string

I'm a newbie to C#, but can't seem to find anything about this problem.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
string testString = txtBox1.Text;
string testString2 = txtBox2.Text;

if ((testString == "") || (testString2 == ""))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a value into both boxes");
    return;
}
```

Basically I need to check to see if either txtBox1 or txtBox2 is blank.  However I'm getting an error when running this.  What's the proper way to do this (or is my approach all wrong)?

Comment: What does "accept" mean?

Comment: sorry I have clarified the problem, my original question did not fully include everything.  I pressed save too soon before I realized it did not cover the actual problem I was having.

Comment: **What's the error?**

Comment: In the code sample you provided, there is a closed parentheses ')' missing in the if.

Comment: @Tibi: the code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Blaisorblade That's because it was edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to check whether textboxes contains any value or not your code should do the job. You should be more specific about the error you are having. You can also do:

```
if(textBox1.Text == string.Empty || textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
   {
    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a value into both boxes");
   }
```

EDIT 2: based on @JonSkeet comments:

Usage of string.Compare is not required as per OP's original unedited post. [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) should do the job if one wants to compare strings, and `StringComparison` may be used to ignore case for the comparison. string.Compare should be used for order comparison. 
Originally the question contain this comparison,

```
string testString = "This is a test";
string testString2 = "This is not a test";

if (testString == testString2)
{
    //do some stuff;
}
```

the if statement can be replaced with

```
if(testString.Equals(testString2))
```

or following to ignore case.

```
if(testString.Equals(testString2,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: I would personally suggest using `Equals` for *equality* comparisons. That's what it's there for, after all.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I agree, I wasn't sure about the original unedited post, if the OP want to compare for equality or wants to compare the strings ignoring case,

Comment: Why on earth would case matter when the OP is comparing for the strings being *empty*? Even if you *do* want to do a case-insensitive comparison, you can still use `Equals` with a `StringComparison`, which is clearer than using `Compare` IMO. `Compare` should be used for an *order* comparison, not equality. I'm amazed this answer has been accepted, as I can't see how it helps the OP with the question as stated.

Comment: @JonSkeet, that was my miss understanding that the OP want's to compare strings, not the empty strings. Earlier there were two string variables with values and OP was comparing them using `==`, later the edited post specified comparing against empty string. Even I am surprised at the answer being accepted. Probably due to edited part of comparing `textBox1.Text == string.Empty`, but again there are other answers using `Equals` which are much better

Comment: Can you mention the reason for using `string.Empty` rather than `""`, if there's any? I'm no good C# programmer (only Java/Scala expert) and the point of `string.Empty` existing at all is not clear to me.

Comment: @Blaisorblade Because `string.Empty` is more explicit.  `""` is a "magic string".  When I come across it in code, I assume the original author wanted an empty string but there is still some doubt.  When I see `string.Empty`, I KNOW for sure what the intent of the code is.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I didn't know that string.Equals could be used for comparing strings with ignore case. That was my mistake and I have update the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more valid way which also check if your textbox is filled with only blanks.

```
// When spaces are not allowed
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox2.Text))
  //...give error...

// When spaces are allowed
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox2.Text))
  //...give error...
```

*The edited answer of @Habib.OSU is also fine, this is just another approach.*

Comment: in your comments you had the 'not' in the wrong place, if the method names make any sense. I assumed it was a typo and edited the answer, please correct it if the current one is actually wrong (but then please explain the weirdness).

Comment: @Blaisorblade No. In OP's code, he's throwing error message when string is equal to empty or contains white-space, so `if string is empty, then throw the error` or `if string is white-space throw the error`.

Comment: I see, sorry. I thought you implemented the intro. I've added comments to clarify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (testString.Equals(testString2)){
}
```

Comment: This is correct, no clue why someone would downvote this other than being a duplicate but posted at the exact same time. Never mind the asholes buddy

Comment: The question is not about comparing the two strings with each other; the code should check if either is empty. The original question was different though and this _was_ a sensible answer, so downvotes are probably not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The code provided is correct, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.
You could also try `if (string1.Equals(string2))` as suggested.

To do `if (something OR something else)`, use `||`:

```
if (condition_1 || condition_2) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `if (testString.Equals(testString2))`.

Comment: The question is not about comparing the two strings with each other; the code should check if either is empty. The original question was different though and this _was_ a sensible answer, so downvotes are probably not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
    {
        // do something..
    }
```

Instead of:

```
    if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty || textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        // do something..
    }
```

Because string.Empty is different than - "".